# jvmti agent deadlock

Tags: deadlock, agent, jvmti

When I run my jvmti agent with a java program, it seems that jvm encounters a deadlock.
In my jvmti agent, I create a single raw monitor in Agent_OnLoad() and enter that lock at the beginning of every callback function and exit that lock at the end of every callback functions.
I don't know the reason of this deadlock. Is there any other possibilities of deadlocks in jvmti agents?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a possibility of deadlocks in JVMTI Agent. The [JVMTI Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jvmti/jvmti.html#RawMonitorEnter) states:

> The same thread may enter a monitor more then once. The thread must
>   exit the monitor the same number of times as it is entered. If a
>   monitor is entered during OnLoad (before attached threads exist) and
>   has not exited when attached threads come into existence, the enter is
>   considered to have occurred on the main thread.

It can be difficult to make a remote diagnosis in this case, but I would suggest you take a look at how the [demo JVMTI applications](http://localdoc.scusa.lsu.edu/java/5-jdk/demo/jvmti/) handle the use of *raw locks*. The use dedicated functions `enter_critical_section` and `exist_critical_section`. Maybe that helps, otherwise try to find the callback which results in a deadlock by debugging the agent.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem when a number of threads call the JVMTI agent concurrently. One thread successfully calls RawMonitorEnter and proceeds. After this a number of other threads call RawMonitorEnter and block, as expected. The thread holding the raw monitor then calls RawMonitorExit, but it appears that this function does not return, which results in the deadlock.

A workaround was to wrap the RawMonitorEnter/Exit and the logic between them in a mutex. This ensured that only one thread at a time would attempt to acquire the raw monitor. The workaround may also negate the need for a raw monitor altogether.