# Dynamic Bytecode Instrumentation fails without any error

Tags: instrumentation, jvm-hotspot, bytecode-manipulation, jvmti

## **Objective**

I'm doing dynamic bytecode instrumentation using a JVMTI agent. I have to instrument those methods which are "hot", that is, the methods which invoke JIT compiler. To do so I listen to a `CompiledLoadEvent` and inside its call back function, call `RetransformClasses`. This in turn invokes `ClassFileLoadHook` on the class containing "hot" function and actual instrumentation begins.

## **Problem Premises**

Currently I'm instrumenting my class to spawn some threads. I also listen to thread starts and print them within my agent. With simple `ClassFileLoadHook` at class load time (without `RetransformClasses`), my instrumentation works perfectly and spawns new threads. I get following output when `ClassFileLoadHook` instruments at class load time:

```
Running Thread: Signal Dispatcher, Priority: 9, context class loader:Not Null
Running Thread: main, Priority: 5, context class loader:Not Null
Running Thread: Thread-0, Priority: 5, context class loader:Not Null
Running Thread: Thread-1, Priority: 5, context class loader:Not Null
Running Thread: Thread-2, Priority: 5, context class loader:Not Null
Running Thread: Thread-3, Priority: 5, context class loader:Not Null
Running Thread: Thread-4, Priority: 5, context class loader:Not Null
Running Thread: Thread-6, Priority: 5, context class loader:Not Null
Running Thread: Thread-5, Priority: 5, context class loader:Not Null
Running Thread: Thread-7, Priority: 5, context class loader:Not Null
Running Thread: DestroyJavaVM, Priority: 5, context class loader:: NULL
```

When I instrument the class file by invoking `RetransformClasses` and then `ClassFileLoadHook`, everything works fine but no threads are spawned and hence no effective instrumentation takes place. VM takes a long time even to execute the original code.

I double checked both instrumentations using -XX:+TraceClassLoading. All the retransformed classes are loaded in both cases. Even the class I'm generating during runtime also gets loaded but no instrumentation happens. Below is the output of class loading trace:

```
[Loaded Test from __VM_RedefineClasses__]
[Loaded Test_Worker_main_0 from file:/home/saqib/workspace/test/bin]
```

I'm generating second class during runtime and it loads into VM but I don't get any thread spawning.

## Questions

- Given my understanding of the problem (There is a high probability
  that I'd be wrong), why `ClassFileLoadHook` retransforms the class
  successfully during load time, but somehow doesn't behave correctly
  when JIT is invoked?
- Just writing the `RetransformClasses` function, with empty
  `ClassFileLoadHook` call back, also takes a lot of time without
  incurring any sort of error. What could be taking time?

## Agent Code

#### Compiled Load Event Call Back

```
static int x = 1;
void JNICALL
compiled_method_load(jvmtiEnv *jvmti, jmethodID method, jint code_size,
        const void* code_addr, jint map_length, const jvmtiAddrLocationMap* map,
        const void* compile_info) {
    jvmtiError err;
    jclass klass;

    char* name = NULL;
    char* signature = NULL;
    char* generic_ptr = NULL;

    err = (*jvmti)->RawMonitorEnter(jvmti, lock);
    check_jvmti_error(jvmti, err, "raw monitor enter");

    err = (*jvmti)->GetMethodName(jvmti, method, &name, &signature,
            &generic_ptr);
    check_jvmti_error(jvmti, err, "Get Method Name");

    printf("\nCompiled method load event\n");
    printf("Method name %s %s %s\n\n", name, signature,
            generic_ptr == NULL ? "" : generic_ptr);

    if (strstr(name, "main") != NULL && x == 1) {
        x++;
        err = (*jvmti)->GetMethodDeclaringClass(jvmti, method, &klass);
        check_jvmti_error(jvmti, err, "Get Declaring Class");

        err = (*jvmti)->RetransformClasses(jvmti, 1, &klass);
        check_jvmti_error(jvmti, err, "Retransform class");

    }

    if (name != NULL) {
        err = (*jvmti)->Deallocate(jvmti, (unsigned char*) name);
        check_jvmti_error(jvmti, err, "deallocate name");
    }
    if (signature != NULL) {
        err = (*jvmti)->Deallocate(jvmti, (unsigned char*) signature);
        check_jvmti_error(jvmti, err, "deallocate signature");
    }
    if (generic_ptr != NULL) {
        err = (*jvmti)->Deallocate(jvmti, (unsigned char*) generic_ptr);
        check_jvmti_error(jvmti, err, "deallocate generic_ptr");
    }

    err = (*jvmti)->RawMonitorExit(jvmti, lock);
    check_jvmti_error(jvmti, err, "raw monitor exit");
}
```

#### Class File Load Hook

```
void JNICALL
Class_File_Load_Hook(jvmtiEnv *jvmti_env, JNIEnv* jni_env,
        jclass class_being_redefined, jobject loader, const char* name,
        jobject protection_domain, jint class_data_len,
        const unsigned char* class_data, jint* new_class_data_len,
        unsigned char** new_class_data) {
    jvmtiError err;
    unsigned char* jvmti_space = NULL;

    if (strstr(name, "Test") != NULL && x == 2) {
        char* args = "op";

        javab_main(2, args, class_data, class_data_len);

        err = (*jvmti_env)->Allocate(jvmti_env, (jlong)global_pos, &jvmti_space);
        check_jvmti_error(jvmti_env, err, "Allocate new class Buffer.");

        (void)memcpy((void*)jvmti_space, (void*)new_class_ptr, (int)global_pos);

        *new_class_data_len = (jint)global_pos;
        *new_class_data = jvmti_space;

        if ( new_class_ptr != NULL ) {
            (void)free((void*)new_class_ptr);
        }

#if DEBUG
        printf("Size of the class is: %d\n", class_data_len);
        for (int i = 0; i < class_data_len; i += 4) {
            if (i % 16 == 0)
                printf("\n");

            printf("%02x%02x  %02x%02x  ", new_class_data[i],
                    new_class_data[i + 1], new_class_data[i + 2],
                    new_class_data[i + 3]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        system("javap -c -v Test_debug");
#endif
        x++;
    }
}
```

Here `javab_main` returns the instrumented `char *` array which is correct. The instrumented array is stored in a global variable `new_class_ptr` which is copied into `new_class_data`. To debug the output of the instrumentation, I also printed the instrumented class in a file called Test_debug and invoking `javap` on it produces desired result.

The complete agent file is given here:
[Agent.c](https://gist.github.com/saqibahmed515/9864ec018edeca14e14ce518131c753c)

## Original Code:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < s; j++) {
                    c2[i][j] = 0;
                    for (int k = 0; k < s; k++)
                        c2[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
                }
```

## Instrumented Code: (Equivalent)

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[NTHREADS];    
            for (int i = 0; i < NTHREADS ; i++) {
                final int lb = i * SIZE/NTHREADS;
                final int ub = (i+1) * SIZE/NTHREADS;
                threads[i] = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        for (int i = lb; i < ub; i++)
                            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
                                c2[i][j] = 0;
                                for (int k = 0; k < SIZE; k++)
                                    c2[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
                            }
                    }
                });
                threads[i].start();
            }

            // wait for completion
            for (int i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++) {
                try {
                    threads[i].join();
                } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
                }
            }
```

## Java Version

```
openjdk version "1.8.0-internal-debug"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-internal-debug-saqib_2016_12_26_10_52-b00)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.71-b00-debug, mixed mode)
```

Comment: You didn’t specify how you modify the instrumented class exactly, but you should be aware, that class initializers will  *not* run again when redefining classes. Also, already ongoing executions of the method’s code won’t turn to the new code, only subsequent executions.

Comment: I am basically trying to parallelize a loop by running multiple instances of the loop in various threads. I have done this by hand and I know that the loop is parallelizable and it works when applied at class load time. When I go from `RetransformClasses` to the `ClassFileLoadHook`, it takes a long time and then execution terminates normally, but no threads are spawn. Even the instrumented and the dynamically generated classes get loaded in VM which I traced by `-XX:+TraceClassLoading`.

Comment: I have also added the java code and equivalent instrumented code in the question. @Holger

Comment: Well, as said, redefining classes won’t change already running executions of the change methods…

Comment: I'm using a patched version of openJDK. It contains enhanced redefining capabilities which allow changing already running executions. Its name is [Dynamic Code Evolution VM (DCEVM)](http://www.ssw.uni-linz.ac.at/Research/Papers/Wuerthinger11PhD/). The patched code repository is given [here](https://github.com/dcevm/dcevm).
This is an Oracle backed project and it does what it says at least in dynamic hit debugging.

Comment: And help me solve the riddle that the dynamically generated class gets loaded in VM but doesn't execute, neither does it throw any error. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: So this question boils down to why this feature, which is normally unsupported, doesn’t work in that special patched JVM that is supposed to add that feature. I’m afraid, I can’t help here…

Comment: Maybe there is a misunderstanding in what the patch is supposed to do. The linked page states that it enables adding members or changing the class hierarchy, but it also says “*Updates can be performed at any point in time and old versions of currently active methods will continue running.*”, which does *not* suggest that already active method executions will turn to the new code.

Comment: Thanks for your input. You pointed out the exact problem. I called my function in a loop and subsequent invocations of the function got instrumented. The slow speed might be due to the fact that compiled code is thrown away and it executes in the interpreted mode again after instrumentation. This is causing a huge overhead. Thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm constructing this answer mainly from the comments. There are still some riddles unsolved but the main question has been resolved. Bytecode instrumentation **does not fail** in my case. It actually **never happens**. According to the theory,

> Dynamic bytecode instrumentation of an executing function takes place
>   at subsequent call of the function. If a function has only one invocation, it cannot be instrumented while execution using current hotswap techniques in JVM.

I was trying to instrument a class which had only one function, i.e. main. I was trying to instrument that during runtime. This was the main problem. To check the validity of this argument, I tried to put my code in another function and called it from main in a loop. It got instrumented and everything worked. Nothing has to be changed in the agent.