# How to retransform an executing method with JVMTI agent which has no further invocations?

Tags: java, jit, instrumentation, jvm-hotspot, jvmti

I am instrumenting a class file during runtime for various purposes. I'm using a JVMTI agent to that end. My strategy to instrument a method is to call `RetransformClasses` function to invoke `ClassFileLoadHook`. This strategy works fine for all the methods which have any further invocation after the time of instrumentation because actual instrumentation happens at subsequent function call, but it doesn't work for any method which does not have further invocations like `main` function in a program.

I want to instrument a method on the fly during its execution. I want some procedure like On-Stack Replacement (OSR) of the instrumented code. Is there any strategy available in JVMTI or any other approach????

PS: I'm open to editing/patching OpenJDK source code if that can help.

Comment: What I don't get: given the fact that such a method will **never** be called; what is the point instrumenting it? I mean: isn't instrumentation about giving you "insight" when the method is called later on; like when the method is invoked?

Comment: You're correct as far as **Instrumentation for profiling** is concerned. I'm instrumenting my code for parallelizing long running loops in a method. So if you have a tedious loop in your `main`, I would like to instrument it to spawn some threads and join em (If it is parallelizable ofcourse). That's why I came across instrumenting single invocation functions.

Comment: Have you looked into javaagent?

Comment: @DennisC Yes. I started off with Javaagent. I tried ASM and Javassist. Javagent also uses same strategy at its backend. For dynamic runtime instrumentation, it'll do the same. That is, instrument subsequent invocations if there are any.

Comment: BTW. Don't trust OSR too much. I read lucene project usually uncover few bug in hotspot due to OSR and optimizer, every time a new jdk released.

Comment: Well I guess that might be a reason for no OSR equivalent in case of instrumentation. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some further thinking, I *believe* you are ask for something that might maybe (maybe!) be possible technically; but require lots of efforts; but **conceptually** it is not a good approach.

I *assume* your requirement is actually that you want to instrument *any* kind of application thrown at you in order to improve its performance by doing "under the cover parallelizing".

So, instead of having a real solution, I mainly have a list of concerns:

- First of all, if you even want to modify methods that were already triggered and that are **currently** executed, you are not only talking about instrumenting. What you actually want to do is to provide your own "JIT" mechanism - while the JVM JIT is also there, and doing its job.
- So, if you are really serious about this; and want to make sure that even the things in any `main()` can benefit from your optimizations - then I think, conceptually, you are better of designing and implementing your *own* JVM then.
- Then I am wondering: you say want to cover `main()` methods that are already running "long time loops". That sounds like you intend to fix **bad designs** by throwing your instrumentation at it. I think the more sane approach is: look into such applications, and **improve** their design.
- In the sense of: if "parallelizing" arbitrary applications would be "that easy" - it would be part of the JVM anyway. And the fact that it is not; and that the JVM doesn't do such kind of optimizations is for a good reason: it is probably **super hard** to get that correct and robust.

In other words: I *guess* you have an XY problem; and the X problem is that the application(s) you are dealing could benefit from "parallelizing". But that is something that is very hard to do "in general".

In that sense; I would rather define some kind of architecture (that might include specific, well-defined steps how an application should "start up"; so that your instrumentation can do its work successfully) and gain experience with that approach first. Meaning: tell your folks to not put "long running loops" into their `main()` in the first place (as said; that alone sounds like pretty bad design to me!).

Comment: You got it more or less. My main concern is to exploit implicit parallelism in java codes with the assumption that I don't have the java source of the application. As far as analysis is concerned, I analyze the bytecode for parallelizability and that works perfectly. Obviously it is really difficult to analyze but that's not my main concern here. I'm simply concerned to redefine my classes on the fly. I'm already instrumenting my classes during class load time and I'm getting my desired results. Now I want to use the JIT profiler to sift some hotspots for me and parallelize only those.

Comment: The reason to use hotspots is also obvious. 
Axiom is: "Every loop is not worth parallelizing. Only the hotpots are." Keeping this in mind, I'm naturally inclined to instrument executing hotspots in the code. And there comes the runtime dynamic instrumentation.

Comment: *I analyze the bytecode for parallelizability and that works perfectly* ... is a pretty bold statement ;-) ... I am wondering what you discovered what zillions of people doing research in this area overlooked so far.

Comment: Yeah. I'm sorry, it gives that impression. :-) What I meant is my system is working so far and I have an end to end prototype. I didn't mean to say that I have found some novel approach to analyze parallelizability. And I have discovered something called [JAVAB](http://www.aartbik.com/JAVAB/index.html). It's a bytecode parallelization tool.

Comment: Still ... sounds interesting. Will this be open source at some point. In any case; I had hoped for my first bounty win, but so far the answer seems not even worth upvoting for the people coming by ... but I will keep thinking; and maybe I have some more helpful content later on.

Comment: Fyi: I put some content into that chat.

Comment: The problem is, OSR is done by generating optimized code in a restricted way so that there is a common point at which the control can be transferred from the old to the new code. That’s relying on the fact that the optimized code still does the same as the old code, at least semantically. Instrumentation allows you to replace the code with some arbitrary code, not required to do the same, not even semantically. Parallelized code is unlikely to have something in common with the sequential code, not to speak of a point for safe transfer of control (in the middle of a loop).

Comment: Thanks. I can't promise I will have much time to look into that, but thanks again!